# How to get create and get the values of elements in a cell based on line break

Tags: google-sheets

I stored the data into one cell, and would like to pick the elements value for each of them based on line-break:

Data

```
Flower
Balloon
Camera
```

Therefore, the values (Flower, Balloon, and Camera) are both in cell A1.
I want to choose the first value (Flower) for cell B1, the second for cell C1, and the final one for cell D1.

Is there a way that we can store the values of the same cell (separate by line-break) into somethings like array and we can pick the expected value by index of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SPLIT()` function and line break `CHAR(10)` as delimiter.

```
=SPLIT(A1,CHAR(10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it would be fixed in place, correct? How could I get around it if I wanted the Balloon to be shown in B1, the Camera in C1, and the Flower as the final element?

Comment: You need `SORT()` function to sort output data.

Comment: I tried with: =SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(H7,CHAR(10))),1,TRUE) but it not what I'm expected, it returned both 3 values in 3 rows, I just wanna pick the value of Balloon in B1

Comment: @user22726736 Are you looking for `=TOROW(SORT(TOCOL(SPLIT(A1,CHAR(10))),1,TRUE))`?

Comment: Nah, I just wan to detect and get the value 'Balloon' only into my target cell

Comment: `index(split(a1,char(10)),2)` should *just pick* the `Balloon`

Comment: @user22726736 So, do you want to catch only second word?

Comment: That's what I looking for, thank you so much